# Не получается инициализировать строку в с++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, строки

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string hi = "Hello";
    return 0;
}
```

Вот это при компиляции выкидывает 2 ошибки:

> Не удалось разрешить символ "operator new" [??2@YAPAXI@Z]
>   (перемещение #1 в разделе "std::_Default_allocate_traits::_Allocate"
>   [?_Allocate@_Default_allocate_traits@std@@SAPAXI@Z]).
>   (c:\users\User\source\repos\lesson1\lesson1\debug\main.new.obj.enc)
>
> Не удалось разрешить символ "operator new", поскольку он был определен
>   в объекте в "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\lib\x86\MSVCRTD.lib",
>   который не был загружен.
>   (c:\users\User\source\repos\lesson1\lesson1\debug\main.new.obj.enc)

Visual Studio

Comment: мне кажется, что у вас не хватает некоторых подключенных библиотек. попробуйте пересоздать проект что ли))

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: Вот только при попытке создать массив из строк тоже там что-то не разрешили, вроде eh vector. Мне теперь каждый раз проекты пересоздавать что ли?

Comment: думаю, что вам нужно разобраться с подключаемыми либами. Скорее всего беда в этом.

Comment: И как с ними разобраться

Comment: дополните вопрос. новый полный код программы + версии студи (если вы в студии), установлен ли у вас компилятор? На какой ОС вы работаете. Причин может быть много, почему у вас не фурычат массивы строк